# Contact form directs to contact.php, but i dont want it do redirect. (sending email DOES work)

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Dont worry, I have already searched a lot of places and tried to watch other forums and videos. Im not trying to make it easy.

When I submit a form on my page it redirect to [www.mypag.com/contact.php](http://www.mypag.com/contact.php).
Im trying to use AJAX so that the form will be sent and the page doesnt redirect. Thank you in advance..

```
                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                <div class="messages"></div>

                <div class="controls">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_name">Fornavn *</label>
                                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit fornavn *" required="required" data-error="Fornavn kræves.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_lastname">Efternavn *</label>
                                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit efternavn *" required="required" data-error="Efternavn kræves.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Din email *" required="required" data-error="Gyldig email kræves.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_number">Dit nummer </label>
                                <input id="form_number" type="text" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit telefonnummer (ikke et krav) ">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_message">Besked *</label>
                                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Din besked *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Vær venlig og skriv en besked før du sender."></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send besked">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is my  JS**

```
    $(function () {
$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "index.html";

        // POST values in the background the the script URL
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://andreas.xn--hjorhy-fya.dk/',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;


                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

               
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
```

**This is my PHP**

```
<?php

    $from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';
    $sendTo = 'Demo contact form <MYEMAILHERE>';
    $subject = 'New message from contact form';
    $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'need' => 'Need', 'email' => 'Email',                 
    'message' => 'Message');
    $okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    try
    {
        if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact         
    form\n=============================\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    }
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) ==         
    'xmlhttprequest') {
        $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $encoded;
    }
    // else just display the message
    else {
        echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
```

**Thanks in advance for everyone that makes time to help me or redirect me to somewhere that might fix this problem..**

*** EDIT ***

This is my whole HTML page, with all the scripts etc. As for now I've moved some scripts before my form, but that didnt help. Im currenty looking for through the logs as plesk web host edition doesnt provice developer console.. only the SSH server does (which i for some reason cant access) As for now, the message is still sent and I recieve them, but Im redirected to contact.php (I dont want a redirect, I want to stay on the same page because I only have 1 page on my website)

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Andreas Hjorhøy Rasmussen</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700%7CRoboto:400,700,300">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/animate.css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.default.css" id="theme-stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <!--here i have my whole sebsite.. information, pictures, blog etc -->
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="contact.js"></script>

  <!-- Kontakt-->
  <section id="contact" data-animate="bounceIn" class="contact-section contact">
      <div class="row" data-animate="fadeInUp">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="heading text-center">
                  <h2>Kontakt mig</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto" data-animate="fadeInUp">
              <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
                  <div class="messages"></div>
                  <div class="controls">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="form_name">Fornavn *</label>
                                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit fornavn *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="form_lastname">Efternavn *</label>
                                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit efternavn *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Din email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="form_number">Dit nummer </label>
                                  <input id="form_number" type="text" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Dit telefonnummer (ikke et krav) ">
                                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="form_message">Besked *</label>
                                  <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Din besked *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send besked">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

    <!-- Had to remove footer because of personal links -->
  <!-- JavaScript files-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery.counterup/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
  <script src="js/front.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks like it ought to work, in principle. What debugging of the JavaScript have you done? Are there any errors in the console? The one thing missing from your question is any information about that sort of thing. (If it's currently redirecting, you may need to tick the "preserve log" button in the console so any errors still show after a refresh

Comment: Also, you've put `url: 'https://andreas.xn--hjorhy-fya.dk/'` as the destination for the AJAX request. Should it not be `url: 'contact.php'`?

Comment: Remove `contact.php` from the action and use `if(isset($_POST))` instead. Until this action is there it will redirect.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah it does work and I do recieve the mails. I just want it to stop redirecting to the page "Contact.php," Also there was no errors in the console. II also removed my link and added back contact.php in the AJX request. thanks for answering

Comment: @Fresz Hi, I removed the contact.php from the action, but where should I place if(isset($_POST)) I know my way around html and css, but i just started on PHP so i know very little of it, sorry.

Comment: @Fresz Hi again, as soon as i removed contact.php from my action on my index.html page, it stopped sending emails. When i put it back i was able to recieve again

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your HTML file? Have you used the Javascript debugger to see if the "submit" code is ever triggered?

Comment: Also, did you miss anything out from the Javascript you showed here? Because if we put your code into a JSFiddle, it shows there's a missing `})` at the end, and the console displays an error: https://jsfiddle.net/futw9L21/

Comment: If we correct that, then it produces the error `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validator is not a function` . https://jsfiddle.net/futw9L21/3/ Are you using an extra jQuery plugin file which enables that function? And do you even need it? Because you seem to have HTML5 validation on your fields already.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I do have the }); closing tag. Forgot to put it in here. I have these JQuery in my HTML file:      <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>       <script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script> and       <script src="vendor/jquery.counterup/jquery.counterup.js"></script>

Comment: I use these scripts after the form  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" </script>
    <script src="contact.js"></script>'

Comment: I'm sorry if doing it very wrong, i've only been doing websites for a month and I really love it. Just need to learn a lot

Comment: Ok. So..you really don't have any console errors? Do you understand how to check for console errors? i.e. open your browser's Developer Tools and go to the Console section. It would appear that you have two versions of jQuery there...that could easily cause problems. Just stick to the newest one, and remove the other one.

Comment: I added all those scripts to the JSFiddle - I had to guess the versions of cookie.js and counterup.js so I just used the most recent I could find, and I only added jQuery once. So this is the closest I can get to your real code. It works, in the sense that when you submit the form, it triggers the AJAX request, and it doesn't redirect. (Of course, the AJAX itself fails, but that's not the main issue you're asking about). See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fqnub29k/

Comment: The only things I can think are a) you haven't included the scripts in the right place in your page (e.g. they all need to be declared _before_ any `<script>` blocks which try to make use of them, or b) you have other script files you haven't mentioned, or c) you have other JavaScript on the page which you haven't mentioned, and then one or more of the above is causing an error which you haven't mentioned, which then causes the whole script to fail.

Comment: `Im currenty looking for through the logs as plesk web host edition doesnt provice developer console`...the Console I'm talking about is in your **browser**, not on the server. Press F12 when you load your page and it will open the Developer Tools (in most browsers. Or there will be a menu item for it). All the major browser vendors provide documentation and tutorials - e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools for Chrome. JavaScript runs in your browser, not on the server, so you need to use the browser's tools to debug it.

Comment: You still have 2 copies of jQuery in there. Remove the second one (vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js)

Comment: And if this is really your entire HTML page, then it's missing `</head>`, `<body>`, `</body>` and `</html>` which are all required tags. Anyway though, your first priority is to check the _browser's_ console for errors.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I did have the <html> </html>. Thank you, you fixed it. It was the vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js that was the problem. It now shows a message on the form itself and I recieved my mmail. I learned a thing or two here..

Comment: That's great. I added that as the answer below, so please mark it as accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 copies of jQuery in your page. This can cause errors, conflicts and other unexpected behaviour, especially if they are not the same version of jQuery. And even if it didn't, it's inefficient and unnecessary.

I suggest removing the second one (`vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js`).